# bin/sh script fails with syntax error: unexpected redirection

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell

I have the following bash script I'm now trying to convert to run using the system shell instead:

```
  1 #!/bin/sh
  2 #testtotal
  3 lines="$(crontab -l | awk '{if(NR>2)print}')"
  4 echo "1..$lines"
  5 counter=1
  6 while read p; do
  7         if [[ -x "$p" ]]
  8         then
  9             echo "ok $counter - $p is executable"
 10         else
 11             echo "not ok $counter - $p is not executable or found"
 12         fi
 13         counter=$((counter+1))
 14 done < <(crontab -l | awk '{if(NR>2)print}' | awk '{print $6}')
```

when I run using "sh" it fails with the error:

```
      ctest: line 14: syntax error: unexpected redirection
```

Can you tell me how to adapt this to run under bin/sh?

Comment: What you have is a bash script with a /bin/sh she-bang line, just to clarify.

Comment: @JeffSchaller yes, when I change the script directive to bash it works fine.  but I need to get it working using /bin/sh.

Comment: Try `<<` instead of  `< <`.  Spaces do matter.

Comment: @eyoung100 that doesn't work.  that gives another error "syntax error: unexpected "(" .

Comment: @eyoung100, `< <(...)` is a redirection from a bash [process substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Process-Substitution)

Comment: @dot, a minor point, you can write `crontab -l | awk 'NR > 2 {print $6}'` using only one awk

Comment: @glennjackman  My mistake as unexpected redirection refers to file redirection in some cases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On line 7, instead of `[[ ... ]]` you want `[ ... ]` or `test ...` (making sure to *always, always, always* quote every variable -- which you've already done, but with `[` it's *not* optional and it's worth repeating for everyone else reading).

```
if [ -x "$p" ]
```

On line 14, you can use a here-document combined with a command substitution to replace the process substitution:

```
done <<EOF
$(crontab -l | awk 'NR > 2 { print $6 }')
EOF
```

This way you avoid running the `while read p` loop in a subshell due to piping into it, so your variables will survive.

That should do it to make this POSIX compliant.

Comment: hi. this works. the only thing is that 'lines="$(crontab -l | awk '{if(NR>2)print}')"" is displaying the results of the command.  got to suppress.   I guess I can try doing a wc -l insteead...

Comment: I can't reproduce that. Maybe your `crontab -l` writes to standard error. Try adding `2>&1` to the `crontab -l` to combine standard error with standard output -- or if you don't want that output, add `2>/dev/null`.

Comment: yeah.  neither of those work.

Comment: Are you sure? This doesn't work?

    `lines="$(crontab -l 2>&1 | awk '{if(NR>2)print}')"`

If not, I can't help you. Insufficient information.

Comment: i had to just replace the first line with these two lines:   `lines="$(cat /etc/crontabs/root|wc -l)"` and then also `tests="$(($lines - 2))"`

Comment: Yea, sure that doesn't work.  That returns a "0".   I don't know how much more info i can give.... I pasted the entire script!  But no worries - you've answered my main question and I figured out the rest.  accepting your answer.  Thanks for the help!